# AOP solution for Logging callouts - outgoing http request and responses

Tags: java, spring, logging, filter

I am developing a spring boot application and implement a javax.servlet.Filter (using HttpServletResponseWrapper and HttpServletRequestWrapper) to intercept incoming http requests and log them. While this works great for incoming calls, I am not sure how to intercept outgoing calls (callouts). I am not sure I bumped into a SO page explaining this for a non SOAP client.

I tried extending the HandlerInterceptorAdapter class and overriding the preHandle() and postHandle() methods but these seem to intercept the incoming requests. I am interested in the outgoing calls.

What would be an aop solution to intercept and log client / outgoing  http requests and responses or callouts?

The callouts use the below helper class:

```
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpRequestBase;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;

@Service
public class CalloutService {
@Autowired
protected HttpClient httpClient;

public CalloutService() {
}

private MessageResponse sendRequest(HttpRequestBase request, Map<String, String> httpHeaders) throws IOException {
    addHttpHeaders(request, getDefaultHeaders());
    addHttpHeaders(request, httpHeaders);
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    String responseBody = IOUtils.toString(entity.getContent(), "UTF-8");
    StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
    return new MessageResponse(statusLine.getStatusCode(), statusLine.getReasonPhrase(), responseBody);
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes. Calls made from my application to external apis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a Spring application you typically make the request using a [RestTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html) this one, can be configured and when needed you can autowired it. Thus, when you configure one, you can set the interceptors for outgoing calls. On this [blog](https://svenfila.wordpress.com/2012/01/05/resttemplate-with-custom-http-headers/) there is an example on how to do it. Hope this helps, but this is basically how to do it.

Another fancier option to configure your `RestTemaplte`, is to create your own. You could do something like this:

```
public class RestTemplate extends org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate implements InitializingBean {
    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() {
        if(this.getInterceptors() == null){
            this.setInterceptors(new LinkedList<>());
        }
        this.getInterceptors().add(new YourInterceptor());
    }
}

private static class YourInterceptor implements ClientHttpRequestInterceptor {
    @Override
    public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request, byte[] body, ClientHttpRequestExecution execution) throws IOException {
        //do what you need to do here with the request
        return execution.execute(request, body);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is a good solution if Rest Template is used to make those callouts.